# OnMouseEnter, OnMouseOver, OnMouseExit.... ect. not working in Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, debugging, unity-game-engine

Unity had once again left me baffled. When the player's mouse hovers over the **UI Image**, slot, "Hello" should've been printed out, but it didn't work. I may have just made the most obvious mistake and seem like a total fool, but **I have made sure that**

1. That I have a box collider on all my UI Elements
2. All My Scripts and Box Colliders Are Enabled
3. That I did not mistype OnMouseEnter()

Sorry to bother you with such a miniscule error, but thank you in advance for helping me!

[image: Code]

[image: Unity]

Answer (score 2):

For working with Unity 4.6+ UI, include UnityEngine.EventSystem in your script. Add all the IPointer interfaces that you want. Finally, make sure your UI item with the script has either an image or a collider added to it. If you go the collider route, add a physics2draycaster component to your camera.

See the link below:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SupportedEvents.html

Comment: I just figured it out a couple of minutes ago. Was about to answer my own question, but then I saw this post.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!